# Reporting dual sim phone stolen

Tags: gsm, imei

A burglar took my phone so I reported it to the police and phone company to blacklist it. They only asked for the first IMEI even though the phone has two IMEI since it can accomodate two SIMs. The IMEIs are consecutive when stripping the check digit at the end.  Can the thief use the other slot with the non blacklisted IMEI?

Answer (score 2):

Both IMEI numbers have to be barred for the barring to be effective. If you only reported one IMEI, the other won't be barred, and can still register on the network. You can resolve this by contacting the phone company to let them know about the mistake.